# Meteor 1.8.0.2 npm error: Cannot find module 'createjs'

Tags: meteor

I tried following Meteor's guide on how to [install npm packages](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#installing-npm) for [createjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs), however I end up with the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'createjs'
```

Here's what I ran in a fresh project:

```
meteor npm install --save createjs
meteor npm install
```

The package shows up as dependency in my local `package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
    "createjs": "^1.0.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1"
  },
```

I try using the package in my body.js as follows:

```js
import createjs from 'createjs';
// tried with standard node require, too:
const createjs = require('createjs');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which version of meteor are you using?

try to switch to a stable version

meteor update --release 1.4.2.3

Comment: I'm on 1.8.0.2, which - at least to my knowledge, is considered a stable version, isn't it? (cf. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/releases)

Comment: you are correct. suggested a way downgrading meteor. this might solve your problem. meteor update --release 1.6.0.1 or upgrade to latest version release/METEOR@1.8.1-beta.16. They are frequently releasing and fixing issues. so please try different versions.

Comment: Hi is it actually in the node_modules folder? When I have similar issues I usually run `rm -rf node_modules` then `meteor npm i` nine times out of ten this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. While `createjs` was in there, I removed `nodes_modules` and re-installed all packages, unfortunately to no avail. I tried creating a new app, tried with a different major version (1.4.4.6) - also, no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not get the package to work I ended up including all relevant files to `client/lib`, importing them using `import './lib/easeljs.js';` inside my client's `main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

> *Note: This is a workaround, may not be the solution to your problem.*

Import the `createjs` library using the CDN by including it in your app's `<head>` tag as below:

```
<head>
    .....
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, you can use `createjs` in your js as below:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage('myCanvas');
console.log(stage);
```